# dividing duplicates by the counter of duplicates

Tags: c++

the program i'm trying to write gets info from user, check duplicate in weight and count those duplicates.

For example,

{10, 40, 30, 40, 30} each 40 and 30 is duplicated 2 times

so it should be {10, 20, 15, 20, 15}

and this is my code:

```
struct Data {
  int id;
  double weight
}
std::sort(p, p + num, acompare);
for (int i = 0; i < num; i += counter) {
    for (counter = 1; i + counter<num&& p[i + counter].weight== p[i].weight; )
        counter++;       // count consecutives dups

    if (counter>1) {     // if more than one, process the dups.  
            cntArr[i] = counter;
            cntArr[counter] = counter;
        } else 
            cntArr[i] = 1;  
}

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    cout << p[i].id << ":" << p[i].weight/ (double) cntArr[i] << endl;
}
```

and the result is like this

input :

1 100

2 100

3 100

4 80

5 80

output :

4 40

5 -9.79969e-08

1 33.3333

2 33.3333

3 -1.18744e-07

How do i fix this?

Comment: Who initializes the members of the structs in `p`? Also, what is the definition of `acompare`?

Comment: I initialized the members of the structs in struct like struct Info { int id = 0; double weight = 0.0} and the definition of acompare is bool acompare(ChildInfo lhs, ChildInfo rhs) { return lhs.weight < rhs.weight; } @AmiTavory

Comment: At the line `cntArr[counter] = counter;` what did you want to do? I though you were finding a number of same value for each elements.. and shouldn't you update the interval in `cntArr` which has same value? like `cntArr[i ~ end of duplicate index]`. I think only the first element of same values contain correct duplicate number in your code..

Comment: Yes that is my problem. I've tried to contain correct duplicate number not only the first element but I don't know how to fix this @astrohsy

Comment: Use a `std::map<int, int>`.  Then this becomes a 4 line program without any need to use `std::sort`, or write incomprehensible loops.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried. But using map of struct makes me more confused :(

Comment: then check 'cntArr[i]' has same value of 'cntArr[i-1]' and if it is same do 'cntArr[i] = cntArr[i-1]'

Comment: @Hmmmmm -- There still is no need for `std::sort`.  This just takes two passes through the data without sorting.

Comment: @Hmmmmm -- Look at one of the answers that shows that I was basically correct.  This becomes a 4 line program using a map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Gosh Its a miracle I'm still trying to understand how to use map and why it works much faster tho Thanks a lot

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for asking again. but even if i need to sort the results, using map is better?

Comment: If you want to sort the results, that's just one more line of code after you've generated the correct data.

Comment: @Hmmmmm `std::sort(counts.begin(), count.end(), [](auto& d1, auto& d2){return d1.weight < d2.weight;});` -- That's the single line that sorts on the weight.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I still don't get it. Is it possible to change the order? because I heard map has its own sort algorithm and user can't change it. and that code doesn't sort on the weight :(

Comment: @Hmmmmm Your original question asked how to output the necessary information, and the answer given to you does this, [along with this updated code that does exactly what you requested](http://ideone.com/mLbvwE).  Anything else you're asking has nothing to do with the original request.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to debug the  specific problem in your code, as it isn't complete (can't copy-paste it to an editor and build it). In particular, not sure what are `p`, `cntArray`, and how they are initialized.

However, fundamentally, this code could be made shorter and more efficient. Instead of sorting (immediate *Θ(n log(n))* complexity), use an [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) to store the multiplicity of each element. Shorter, fewer potential bugs, and (expected) linear complexity.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> a{10, 40, 30, 40, 30};
    std::unordered_map<int, std::size_t> counts; 
    std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int e){ ++counts[e]; });
    std::for_each(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
        [&](int e){ std::cout << e / static_cast<double>(counts[e]) << std::endl; });
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ ./a.out 
10
20
15
20
15
```

Comment: The OP is using a `Data` struct, but your answer is still valid.  [See here for an example](http://ideone.com/mLbvwE)