# count duplicates and store those counters in array c++

Tags: c++

Let's say I have {6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 1}
6 is duplicated 2 times, 8 is duplicated 2 times.
each duplicates should be divided by counters. so it should be {3,3,4,9,4,1}.

To do this, I'm trying to make counter array

e.g. cntArray{2,2,2,1,2,1} (2: duplicated 2 times)

so that I can divide those numbers by counters

{6,6,8,9,8,1} / {2,2,2,1,2,1} = {3,3,4,9,4,1}

and I haven't learned about map so want to do this by using vector, sort without using map.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> id_v;
    vector<int> gram_v;
    int id, gram = 0;
    int childNum = 0;
    int counter;
    int *cntArr = new int[0];

    cout << "Enter the number of children : ";
    cin >> childNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        cin >> id >> gram;
        id_v.push_back(id);
        gram_v.push_back(gram);
    }

    std::stable_sort(gram_v.begin(), gram_v.end(), acompare);
    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        for (counter = 1; i + counter < childNum && gram_v[i + counter] == gram_v[i];)
            counter++;

        if (counter > 1) {
//          cntArr[gram_v[i]] = counter;    //cntArr[100] = 2;
            for (int j = counter; j > 0; j--)
                gram_v[i - j + 1] /= counter;
            counter = 1;
        } else {
//          cntArr[gram_v[i]] = counter;    //cntArr[60] = 1;
            gram_v[i] /= counter;
        }

        cout << gram_v[i] << "\t" << endl;
    }
}
```

or please give me some better idea!

Comment: Look up `std:map<int, int>` and use `YourMap[YourKey]++;` trick to count duplicates. Will get you much easier/cleaner approach.

Comment: @FirstStep I'm not allowed to use map :(

Comment: why do you think a map would be better?

Comment: Does your code work? What are you asking?

Comment: @RichardHodges Did you try to ping me? Because the code would be easier to read or/and maintain. And a map has faster access time. `log(n)`

Comment: @Hmmmmm all your numbers are less than 10?

Comment: Are there missing braces after the 2nd `for` loop?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how do i count duplicates and store the counters by sorting vector? please give me more hint :(

Comment: @FirstStep no that's just an example all the numbers should be less than 10000000

Comment: @Hmmmmm Oh. I will edit my answer. But what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Beta it works but not properly I've tried to divide those numbers by counters but it doesn't work. so I'm asking how to store all the counters in array in same index as int s array

Comment: @FirstStep so if I enter 100, 100, 80, 60, 80 then it results 60,40,80,50,100, not 60,40,40,50,50 This is why I'm trying to make counter array but no idea how to make array to store all the counters

Comment: @Hmmmmm The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest approach for numbers 0->9 that I can think of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> MyVec = {6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 1};
    int Counters[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }; // indexes will represent numbers from 0->9

    for (int i = 0; i < MyVec.size; i++) // count each number
    {
        Counters[MyVec[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MyVec.size; i++) // replace each number with it self divided by its counter
    {
        MyVec[i] = Counters[MyVec[i]];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For input data other than 0->9, and following Thomas Matthews design. This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Number_Counts
{
    int element;
    int counter;
    Number_Counts(int _element) { element = _element; counter = 1; }
};

bool IncrementIfFound(std::vector<Number_Counts> &, int );
int GetCounter(std::vector<Number_Counts>, int);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> OriginalData = {6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 1};
    std::vector<Number_Counts> MyVector; 

    for (int i = 0; i < OriginalData.size(); i++) // populate counters
    {
        if (!IncrementIfFound(MyVector, OriginalData[i])) // if true, would be incremeneted already, if false, add as new 
        {
            Number_Counts temp(OriginalData[i]);
            MyVector.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < OriginalData.size(); i++) // submit new value (old / its counter)
    {
        OriginalData[i] /= GetCounter(MyVector, OriginalData[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool IncrementIfFound(std::vector<Number_Counts> &_Container, int _element)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < _Container.size(); i++ )
        if (_Container[i].element == _element)
        {
            _Container[i].counter++;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
int GetCounter(std::vector<Number_Counts> _Container, int _element)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _Container.size(); i++)
        if (_Container[i].element == _element)
            return _Container[i].counter;
}
```

Results:

Input: 
`{6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 1}`

Output: 
`3 3 4 9 4 1`

Comment: `size()` is a function. Also, this approach won't work if you have huge integers (not sure if this is pertinent to this question, it does work for the example dataset).

Comment: @krzaq I wrote this before I knew that integers might be other than 0->9. Writing another answer now. And yes you are right about `size` as I did not write that using an IDE. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a structure to track the values and their counts:

```
struct Number_Counts
{
  int value;
  int count;
};
```

You can make a vector of these:

```
std::vector<Number_Counts> value_counts;
```

To count the occurrences:

```
For each data item do:
  search `value_counts` for the value.
  if value exists, increment the counter.
  else add new entry to the value_counts vector.
```

Since your assignment is not graded on execution time, a simple linear search of the `value_count` will suffice.

**Edit 1:**
Searching for a value in the `value_counts` vector:

```
const unsigned int size = value_counts.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  if (value == value_counts[i].value)
  {
    // Value exists already, so increment the counter
    ++value_counts[i].count;
    break;
  }
}
if (i >= size)
{
  // value was not found, so append a new entry
  Number_Counts nc;
  nc.value = value;
  nc.counts = 1;
  value_counts.push_back(nc);
}
```

Comment: And then iterate all of Original Container to divide each element by its final counter and to replace it with its new value, to meet the requirement.

Comment: I'm still so confused What does that "search 'value_counts' for the value" mean? +@FirstStep

Comment: @Hmmmmm See my new answer. (cc Thom)

Comment: See my latest edit on how to search a vector of structures.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you're unfamiliar with dictionary data structures. FWIW, I still think that [the answer using `std::unordered_map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684424/dividing-duplicates-by-the-counter-of-duplicates/39684610#39684610) is the way to go here (it has lower expected complexity), and, if necessary, you should read up on data structures.

Having said that, once your `vector` is sorted, it is easy to find the multiplicity of an element:

- [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) will find, with logarithmic complexity (through a variation of binary search), the pair of iterators corresponding to it.
- Given the pair of iterators, you can find their distance using [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

So, your loop could be simplified to this:

```
std::sort(gram_v.begin(), gram_v.end());
for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
    const auto eq = equal_range(gram_v.begin(), gram_v.end(), id_v[i]);

    cout << id_v[i] / static_cast<double>(std::distance(eq.first, eq.second)) <<  endl;
}
```

Note that since you're sorting the vector, the subsequent loop doesn't increase the order of growth.

P.S. You don't need stable sort in this case.